# What is difference between compiling TypeScript to seperate modules or a single file?

Tags: typescript

Besides the obvious (hah).

I'm still no sure why you would choose either of those.

I used to think compiling a single file was easier, as you use `<reference>`s to link files and can use nested modules to manage a global namespace.

But now I'm thinking that `import/require` and many output files might be good for greater modularity (and similarity to regular JavaScript / ES6).

But can you namespace types adequately using imports? Using extra level of modules seems awkward when importing.

And won't we still need `<references>` to resolve the type annotations?

How do I decide on this?

Comment: Have you read this? It covers most of your questions https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript

Comment: just thought I'd share this as well ;) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: Thanks for the link to the manual, I wasn't even aware it existed! Digging into it right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used to think compiling a single file was easier, as you use `<reference>`s to link files and can use nested modules to manage a global namespace.

Basically using --out:

Pro: Simple to begin with. Types are importable via simple `<reference` comments.

Con: Single file. Not easy to debug if you debug JS.

> But can you namespace types adequately using imports?

You should not use *internal modules* when you are using external modules. For external modules (amd/commonjs) each file is its own module. That will avoid that "extra / unnecessary" level of indirection.

> And won't we still need  to resolve the type annotations?

No. As soon as you `export` something at the root level `///<reference`ing that file no longer does anything. The only way to import types (even interfaces) from such a file is to use `import/require`

## Note:

To overcome to get the pros of `--out` i.e easy type import via `///<reference` + still allow simpler debugging of JS, grunt-ts supports generating an amd-loader for you: https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#advantage-of-using-amdloader-option

Comment: For `import/require` I fear creating unresolvable dependency loops, but worth a try. The amdLoader sound good (I'm still hazy on the practical details), but could it also work for commonjs (node)?

Comment: `could it also work for commonjs (node)` it will need to be different implementation. And tricky since it is best to use `import/require`.

Comment: `I fear creating unresolvable dependency loop` : if a needs b and b needs a, and a is the first to execute, a gets b as null and needs to handle it

Comment: For values it is solvable, but with `import` it gets wonky if you want to declare types: if A has a method that returns a B, and B has a method that returns an A, then import ordering would be problematic.